# Linq query with left join having multiple tables

Tags: .net, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

This is my linq query

```
    from row in (
    from c in db.TabC
    from cpd in db.TabPD
    from slm in db.TabSLM
    where cpd.SLid == slm.SLid
    where c.Id == cpd.CID
    where c.O_Id == 1
    select new { c, cpd, slm })
group row in row.slm.SLType into g
select new
{
    SLType = g.Key,
    EStat = g.Count(r => r.c.EstatID != null),
    Training = g.Count(r => r.cpd.TrId != null),
    TrainingComplete =
        g.Count(r => r.cpd.TrStat == 44),
    AssessmentComplete =
        g.Count(r => r.cpd.CndAssess == 44)
};
```

I need to make a left join to table db.TabSLM and get as many records as there are in that table. TabC is a master table and so is TabSLM. TabPD has detail records that references both TabC and TabSLM. With this query, when there are no matches in TabPD for either TabC rowid or TabSLM rowid, I get no records returned. What I want is to return the number of records present in TabSLM incase there are no matches. Any ideas on how to modify this query?

Here is below is the sample data for each of the three tables with minimal fields listed

```
TabC
ID  O_ID   Name
1       1     ABC
2       1     XYZ
3       1     RST

TabPD
RowID    CID    SLid 
1        2      1
2        1      1
3        3      2
4        ...

TabSLM
SLid   SLType
1      single level 
2      Multi level
```

With the query above, I am able to get records where TabC.O_ID == 1, but not where TabC.O_ID == 3 because TabC.O_ID doesn't have any records with ID == 3. I still want to display SLType with the other columns showing as 0

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356814.aspx)

```
var query =
    from row in (
      from c in db.TabC
      join cpd in db.TabPD on c.Id equals cpd.CID
      from slm in db.TabSLM.Where(x => cpd.SLid == x.SLid)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
      where c.O_Id == 1
      select new { c, cpd, slm })
group row by row.slm.SLType into g
select new
{
    SLType = g.Key,
    EStat = g.Count(r => r.c.EstatID != null),
    Training = g.Count(r => r.cpd.TrId != null),
    TrainingComplete =
        g.Count(r => r.cpd.TrStat == 44),
    AssessmentComplete =
        g.Count(r => r.cpd.CndAssess == 44)
};
```

Comment: Also, "group row in row.slm.SLType into g" doesn't work. "group row by row.slm.SLType into g" did.

Comment: @user20358 - I updated the query slightly. Without seeing tables *TabC*, *TabPD*, *TabSLM* I won't be able to know the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Just try this once:

```
var query =
    from row in (
      from c in db.TabC
      join cpd in db.TabPD on c.Id equals cpd.CID into temp
                          from cpd in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
      from slm in db.TabSLM.Where(x => cpd.SLid == x.SLid)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()
      where c.O_Id == 1
      select new { c, cpd, slm })
group row by row.slm.SLType into g
select new
{
    SLType = g.Key,
    EStat = g.Count(r => r.c.EstatID != null),
    Training = g.Count(r => r.cpd.TrId != null),
    TrainingComplete =
        g.Count(r => r.cpd.TrStat == 44),
    AssessmentComplete =
        g.Count(r => r.cpd.CndAssess == 44)
};
```